# Scraping html table with odd format and <h> </h> tags

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to pull the table info within `h9`.  It runs, but only prints the head "company info" to the csv.  I've tried ditching the `df.to_csv` and just print it out, and it prints this

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [company_info]
Index: []
```

doesn't `infos` grab the information within `h9`?

Any help is appreciated

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.crb.state.ri.us/licensedetail.php?link=28637&type=Resid'

data = r.get(url)

page_data = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')

infos = (info.text for info in page_data.table.tr.find_all('h9'))

df = pd.DataFrame(infos, columns=['company_info'])

df.to_csv('RI_company_info.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What is this 'h9' refering to is it a tag name ?

Comment: it sure is.  <h9>
                                         <br>
     Heliomar            T     Desouza             <br>
     17 NEWPORT AVENUE                  <br>
     NEWPORT            ,
     RI&nbsp;
     02840<br>
     (401)855-2723</h9>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax

```
"page_data.table.tr"
```

is invalid. You can find for the "h9" elements directly:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.crb.state.ri.us/licensedetail.php?link=28637&type=Resid'
data = r.get(url)
page_data = soup(data.text, 'html.parser')
# Clean up the output.
infos = (' '.join(info.get_text(", ", strip=True).split()) for info in page_data.find_all('h9'))
df = pd.DataFrame(infos, columns=['company_info'])
df.to_csv('RI_company_info.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

> company_info
>
> "Heliomar T Desouza, 17 NEWPORT AVENUE, NEWPORT , RI 02840, (401)855-2723"
>
> "STATUS:, VALID"

Alternatively use

```
infos = (' '.join(info.get_text(", ", strip=True).split()) for info in page_data.select('table tr h9'))
```

Comment: that's awesome.  from trying so many different solutions, i think i got jumbled with the find and find_all.  Totally appreciate the help. Btw, i noticed that the "Status:, Valid" is in a separate row due to it being in a different table.  How would one go about adding it to the same cell as infos?

Comment: use "infos = [' '.join(' '.join(info.get_text(", ", strip=True).split()) for info in page_data.find_all('h9'))]"

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer and/or vote for it, if it answered your original question :-)